AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value: (0, _assert().default)(node.type === OPTION)
at RequestGraph.invalidateOptionNodes (food-ordering-app\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:249:29)
at loadRequestGraph (food-ordering-app\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:872:18)
at async RequestTracker.init (food-ordering-app\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:822:17)
at async Parcel._init (food-ordering-app\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:188:28)
at async Parcel.watch (food-ordering-app\node_modules@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:260:7)
at async run (food-ordering-app\node_modules\parcel\lib\cli.js:283:9)
{
generatedMessage: true,
code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
actual: false,
expected: true,
operator: '=='
}
I was running the command npx start in my vs code terminal, after the development server started I refreshed the page several times to view my shimmer ui effect after which it gave this error.

Delete .parcel-cache file and then run your code
